# Ocean Modifier > Bake Ocean > Foam Fade... How does it work?

Tags: ocean-simulation

I'm curious how the Foam Fade slider works exactly.  I'm assuming a higher value means more foam accumulates over time, but I wanted to check just in case.

Also, if I'm not mistaken, you cannot preview this, correct?  You just have to bake it and then use the bake in order to see how it works?

Comment: Yes that's what is written (Baked Ocean Only)

Comment: Thanks @moonboots, after tinkering I understand it now.  I also discovered the answer to the first question, in case this helps anyone else, that a higher value means more foam.  I suppose this is probably obvious but I always think of a "fade" as less of something, so my dyslexic brain wasn't sure if a higher value meant "more fading" (i.e. less) ;)

Comment: maybe write your own answer, it may help someone   ;)

Comment: @moonboots done ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After more research I've learned the answer to my question:

Foam Fade is the duration for how long foam lasts after it is created.  The higher the value the more the foam builds up, so to speak.  So a higher value essentially means more foam.

You cannot preview the Foam Fade because the data is only created in the bake.

One more thing to note, and I didn't realize this before, is that the Ocean modifier is best used as a displacement map in a texture.  The goal is to set up an ocean how you like it and then bake it, and use the image sequence from the bake as a displacement map for a separate plane object.  You can also add the foam to this texture and blend the two image maps together to create your ocean texture.  I would add some noise as well to the bump/normals to add more detail.